# How do I read bytes from InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I want to test that the bytes I write to `OutputStream`(a file OuputStream) is same as I read from same `InputStream`.

**Test** looks like

```
  @Test
    public void testStreamBytes() throws PersistenceException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String uniqueId = "TestString";
        final OutputStream outStream = fileService.getOutputStream(uniqueId);
        new ObjectOutputStream(outStream).write(uniqueId.getBytes());
        final InputStream inStream = fileService.getInputStream(uniqueId);
    }
```

I realized that `InputStream` doesn't have `getBytes()`.

How can I test something like

```
assertEquals(inStream.getBytes(), uniqueId.getBytes())
```

Thank you

Comment: To add: String#getBytes() assumes system default character set when encoding the string to bytes, don't forget. There is no way to "just get the bytes from a String" since that's only possible by encoding each character to one or more bytes using a character set.

Answer (score 3):

Try this( IOUtils is commons-io)

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(instream);
```

Comment: I believe IOUtils is commons-io, doesn't `Java` provides something similar?

Comment: @daydreamer yes, using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16384];

while ((nRead = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
  buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}

buffer.flush();
```

and check using:

```
assertEquals(buffer.toByteArray(), uniqueId.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read from inputstream and write on ByteArrayOutputStream then use [toByteArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29)  method to convert it to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't provide exactly what you want, but you could wrap the streams you're using with something like a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
new PrintWriter(outStream).print(uniqueId);
String readId = new Scanner(inStream).next();
assertEquals(uniqueId, readId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try something like this?

```
@Test
public void testStreamBytes()
    throws PersistenceException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  final String uniqueId = "TestString";
  final byte[] written = uniqueId.getBytes();
  final byte[] read = new byte[written.length];
  try (final OutputStream outStream = fileService.getOutputStream(uniqueId)) {
    outStream.write(written);
  }
  try (final InputStream inStream = fileService.getInputStream(uniqueId)) {
    int rd = 0;
    final int n = read.length;
    while (rd <= (rd += inStream.read(read, rd, n - rd)))
      ;
  }
  assertEquals(written, read);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. You have to advance the offset independently of the last read count.